# Dart Firestore add to array

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm writing a Flutter app and am trying to add an element to an array. I'm trying to follow the example here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array - however, My DocumentReference object does not have an update object:

[image]

So, how do I go about adding an element to an array in this document?

For reference, I'm using the cloud_firestore: 0.12.1 dependency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method you should use is updateData(). You pass to it a map.

Here is an example adding an element (the string 'element') to an array (named loosely 'arrayName') :

```
userPantry.updateData({'arrayName': FieldValue.arrayUnion(['element'])})
```

Comment: Ah, I'd tried that method but couldn't get it to work. I was just using it incorrectly. Thanks!